# Blazor media stream API

Tags: javascript, blazor

I'm new to Blazor and trying to put together a very simple screen sharing app. I've got the below, when I click the Start Stream button it shows the stream selection dialog, and indicates the screen is being captured, but I can't see the stream in the video element.

Am I way off? Or just missing something simple?

Razor Page

```
@using System.Drawing;
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

<h3>Capture</h3>
<div style="width:80%;background: grey;margin: auto;">
    <video id="video" autoplay playsinline muted></video>
</div>
<div style="width:80%;margin: auto;padding-top:10px ;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="StartStream">Start Stream</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="StopStream">Stop Stream</button>
</div>

@code {

    private async void StartStream()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("startCapture");
    }

    private async void StopStream()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("stopCapture");
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
const videoElem = document.getElementById("video");

// Options for getDisplayMedia()
var displayMediaOptions = {
    video: {
        cursor: "always",
        height: 1000,
        width: 1200
    },
    audio: false
};

// Start the screen capture
async function startCapture() {
    try {
        let mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
        videoElem.srcObject = mediaStream;
        dumpOptionsInfo();
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error("Error: " + err);
    }
}

// Stop the stream
function stopCapture(evt) {
    let tracks = videoElem.srcObject.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
    videoElem.srcObject = null;
}

// Dump the available media track capabilities to the console
function dumpOptionsInfo() {
    const videoTrack = videoElem.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
    console.info("Track settings:");
    console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getSettings(), null, 2));
    console.info("Track constraints:");
    console.info(JSON.stringify(videoTrack.getConstraints(), null, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it, adding incase it helps anyone else.

Change the start capture to this.

```
async function startCapture() {
   try {
       var video = document.querySelector('video');

       let mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
       video.srcObject = mediaStream;
   } catch (err) {
       // Handle error
       console.error("Error: " + err);
   }
}
```